# Flutter - XMLHttpRequest has been bloked by CORS policy

Tags: php, json, api, flutter

I'm working on Flutter and in my php API, I put these headers :

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
```

but I still have the anserw :

"`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/spring_box/api.php' from origin 'http://localhost:52502' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`"

Can you help me to solve my problem please?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps

1- Go to flutter\bin\cache and remove a file named: flutter_tools.stamp

2- Go to flutter\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\web and open the file chrome.dart in Text editor.

3- Search & find '--disable-extensions'

4- Add '--disable-web-security'

5- Save. and Try Now

Happy Coding.